# Как запускать скрипт при каждом срабатывании аякса?

Tags: javascript, ajax, вёрстка

Как после каждого запроса Аякса, после прорисовки верстки, запускать скрипт. Пробовал в success, но не срабатывает. Скрипт переносит содержимое одного дива в другой. И с первым же срабатыванием аякса этот перенос анулируется.

нужный скрипт

```
var one = document.querySelector('.pagination-block'),
two = document.querySelector('.for-pagination-block');
while (one.lastChild) {
two.insertBefore(one.lastChild, two.firstChild);
}
```

Аякс с success частью

```
    $.ajax({
    url: window.location.origin.concat($url_load_products),
    type: 'post',
    data: data,
    async: false,
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
        window.showNotify('danger', 'Ошибка', jqXHR.responseText);
},

//Успешный запрос
success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
     loading_content_of_shop = false;

    $('#shop-content').empty().append(data);

    $('ul.pagination a').click(function(){
       load_content_of_shop(this, $(this).attr('data-page'));
     });


    if (typeof after_load_content_of_shop == 'function') { 
            after_load_content_of_shop();

    }


    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Сделайте функцию и вызывайте её в нужно вам месте

Comment: "этот перенос анулируется" - смысл этой фразы известен только Вам